# What is the difference between Pipelines - Create and Definitions - Create in Azure DevOps REST API?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I was trying to create a yml pipeline with [Pipeline - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) Azure DevOps REST API and it was throwing an exception 'No pool was specified' even though I have mentioned pool in the yml file. More details of this issue is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68758184/pipeline-creation-with-azure-devops-rest-api-fails-with-error-no-pool-was-speci).
Please find below, the request body used for creating pipeline.

```
{
"folder": "",
"name": "pipeline-by-api",
"configuration": {
    "type": "yaml",
    "path": "/azure-pipelines.yml",
    "repository": {
        "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "name": "repo-by-api",
        "type": "azureReposGit"
    }
}
```

Then I identified a second REST API, [Definitions - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and using this I was able to successfully create a pipeline. Please find below the request body used for creating build definition.

```
    {     
     "process":{
       "yamlFilename":  "azure-pipelines.yml"
     },
     "queue":{
       "pool":{
         "name": "Azure Pipelines"
        }
     },
     "repository": {
       "id":  "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
       "type":  "TfsGit",
       "name":  "repo-by-api",                       
       "defaultBranch":  "refs/heads/master"
     },  
     "name":  "pipeline-by-api",  
     "path":  "\\API-Test",
     "type":  "build",
     "queueStatus":  "enabled"
    }
```

I would like to understand what's the difference between the two. I have tried [Definitions - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) as [Pipelines - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) was not working for me. But is this a correct way of creating pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

`Definitions - Create` is an older endpoint. It was availabe before YAML pipeline becomes first class citizens. `Pipelines - Create` is a new endpoint suited for YAML pipelines. Both can be used to create pipeline and if you change API version to 4.1 you will see that `Pipelines` is not available.

[image]

If I have to guess, they find a reason to create a new endpoint for handling yaml pipelines, probably to avoid some breaking changes, but this is only a guess.

Comment: Pipeline - Create only available starting 6.0 onward , and I have same guess as well to avoid breaking changes - you can notice that with `preview` flag with Pipeline - Create but not Definitions - Create